# How to apply accuracy_score function to two columns in group by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have the following data frame:

```
wn  Ground_truth   Prediction
A        1              1
A        1              1
A        1              0
A        1              1
B        0              1
B        1              1
B        0              0
```

for each group ( A , B) i would like to calculate the accuracy_score(Ground_truth, Prediction)

Comment: does groupby apply not work?

Comment: couldn't figure out how to use group by apply in this case.

Comment: `df.groupby('wn').apply(lambda x: accuracy_score(x['Ground_truth'], x['Prediction']))` should do it

Comment: Great! thanks, how can i assign a column name to the result? having it in a format like wn,accuracy columns?

Comment: apparently with .reset_index(name="accuracy")

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for accuracy you can actually do something simpler:

```py
df.assign(x=df['Ground_truth']==df['Prediction']).groupby('wn').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `accuracy_score` function from `sklearn`. You can check their document from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

ground_truth = df["Ground_truth"].values
predictions = df["Prediction"].values

accuracy = accuracy_score(ground_truth, predictions)
```